# HTML/CSS Table make all columns take up needed space besides one in middle take up rest free space, without expanding table size outside parent

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

Tried searching high and low but only found semi-workarounds that feels inefficient.

I have a table inside a div that I don't want to expand outside that div.

Inside the table I have 7 columns; column 1+3-7 ('small' columns)i want to take up the space they need to fit their text (status, username, category etc., which'll take up what, 20-30% of the table's width) and column 2 ('large' column) should take up the remaining available space but not (!) expand the tables size so it goes outside the parent div.

I can get it semi-working using `table-layout: fixed;`, but that makes all the containers that should only take up the space they need expand with whitespace and I would've liked not having to set specific sizes for all columns, but rather as I've written having the 'small' columns take up the size they need (but not more) and the 'large' column take up what remaining space is available.

Optimally I would like to just have two classes in my `custom.css` named small and large (or whatever) in which I apply the large class to the large column (increase size as much as possible, but don't make the table go outside the parent div. hide overflow text with ellipsis if needed or else just have empty space so row takes up 100% of table width) and the 'small' class which i add to all small columns takes up as much space as they need to fit the text (i.e. `white-space: nowrap;`) but no extra whitespace (which I get with `table-layout: fixed;`).

tl;dr:

Not using `table-layout:fixed` (don't want to set column widths specifically).

Table with several columns, all but one in the middle take up the space they need but not more (`white-space: nowrap`).

That one large td should take up the rest of the space but don't increase size of table, nor expand outside table. Use overflow ellipsis if too much text.

Edit:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mwsqnmgw/1/

HTML

```
<table id="codexpl">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Columna</th>
        <th>Relative</th>
        <th>Isso</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>This</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>Is</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>this</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>is</td>
        <td>not equals</td>
        <td>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>the</td>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td>real</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>first</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Column</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.small-td{
  width:1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.large-td{
  width: 99%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

#codexpl th, #codexpl td{
    padding:0.8em;
    border: 1px solid;
}
#codexpl th{
    background-color:#6699FF;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Edit:

Finally managed to solve it. Will write fix after I've removed some testcode so I know what actually did it.

Edit:

What I had to do was add max-width: 1px; to the 'large' column (`max-width: 1%` wouldn't work it seems), so I have two classes added to the th's and all td's.

```
.small{
    width:1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.large{
    max-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Please provide code - instead of a large complicated explanation

Comment: @Peter Sorry. Thought i should write the text first then fix a jsfiddle. Should've done it all beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need? For `table` the `max-width` is defined.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: thin solid red;
}

table {
  max-width: 100%;
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: thin solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>user</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin leo metus, pellentesque ut dui nec, rhoncus efficitur ipsum. Fusce facilisis urna in auctor commodo. Nulla non lectus sed purus porttitor vulputate. Cras aliquam tortor ut tempor commodo.
        Curabitur aliquet magna vitae tellus condimentum, sit amet commodo quam vulputate. Morbi eros felis, tincidunt ut tortor eget, tincidunt iaculis ex. Aliquam luctus orci eget est congue viverra. Curabitur auctor erat eu purus bibendum, eget aliquet
        tellus scelerisque. In lacinia risus vel erat pretium, id sollicitudin nisl feugiat. Maecenas eu efficitur nulla, non viverra sem. Proin quis finibus lorem, ac rhoncus erat. Curabitur odio purus, condimentum eu neque vitae, aliquam mattis libero.
        Cras eleifend gravida velit non ultricies. Aliquam vel vestibulum quam. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</td>
      <td>category</td>
      <td>product</td>
      <td>address</td>
      <td>zipcode</td>
      <td>place</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If i set container width to 100% it expands outside of Its parent container (although encloses the table nicely). So still doesn't solve the problem. I dont want the table to increase in size due to 2nd column (and thus going outside parent div).

Here is an image of that. The below table shouldn't go further to the right than roughly the 2nd button that can be seen in the top-right corner.

http://imgur.com/a/Mv3hR

Answer (score -1):

Something like this maybe?

```css
table, tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.smallCol {
  width: 5% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="smallCol"></td>
<td></td>
<td class="smallCol"></td>
<td class="smallCol"></td>
<td class="smallCol"></td>
<td class="smallCol"></td>
<td class="smallCol"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

There are probably bettere efficient ways to get to this result, but this does the trick for now. Let me know if any questions. Hope it helps.

Comment: Using your above code still makes my 2nd column write out all of its text and expands the table outside the parent <Div>. See this imgur.



Edit: Sorry, i'm not used to posting here or imgur. It's processing the picture atm :P. Will update when it's up.

Edit: Ok this link works http://imgur.com/a/JidzX

Comment: Don't encourage unnecessary use of `!important`.